# Ionic: receive push notification based on geolocation

Tags: javascript, mobile, push-notification, geolocation, ionic-framework

I'm developing a Ionic Mobile app and I've just started working on my push notifications module. I'm now receiving the push notifications well, using Ionic Push Alpha and Google GCM.

My problem appears, when, inside my app, I want to let the user to configure receiving notifications or not, and receive notifications based on it's own geolocation.

Should I send the push notification to all device tokens I have stored, and each device decide (based on the current position) if it should show the notification or not? Is that possible?

Is there any other possibility to do this?

Thanks!